# How can I achieve in Ruby to dump all variables, according to the actual binding, when the program is interrupted?

Tags: ruby, variables, binding, dump, sigint

I would like to achieve that my Ruby program dump all variables, maybe constants if possible, to the screen, or into a file, according to the actual binding, when the program is interrupted, either due some error or when Ctrl+C was pressed.
I can easily do this by applying begin rescue end structure, and placing "binding.pry" into the rescue clause, using the Pry gem:

```
begin
  <my program>
rescue => e
  binding.pry
end
```

When the program contains sub-programs, methods, functions, it is not so easy to achieve this, as I should have to place such a construct in every function definition, as far as I know.

Comment: Just googling this myself out of interest, maybe this "heap dump" guide would be useful https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-ruby-heap-dumps-part-i/